# Displaying saved data from local storage onto html page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing a school project in which I'm creating webpages to allow users to input and then display it on another page. On the Create An Event page is a form. I have saved all the input into local storage but now I am unsure on how to retrieve the data to display in on another page called Event Description. Here are my codes:

```
function saveToStorage() {
     var nameofevent=document.getElementById("name").value;
     var pList=document.getElementsByName("pos");
     var positions=[];

     for (i=0; i<pList.length; i++){
     positions.push(pList[i].value);
     console.log(pList[i].value);
     }

     //for (i=0; i<positions.length; i++){
     //console.log(positions[i].value);
     //}

     var venue= document.getElementById("venue").value;
     var date=document.getElementById("date").value;
     var starttime=document.getElementById("timeStart").value;
     var endtime=document.getElementById("timeEnd").value;
     var contact=document.getElementById("contact").value;
     var email=document.getElementById("email").value;
     var desc=document.getElementById("desc").value;

     var one={"name":nameofevent,"pos":positions,"venue":venue,"date":date,"timeStart":starttime,"timeEnd":endtime,"contact":contact,"email":email,"desc":desc};
     localStorage["CreateEvent"]=JSON.stringify(one);


     return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
localStorage["CreateEvent"]=JSON.stringify(one);
```

...should be:

```
localStorage.setItem('CreateEvent', JSON.stringify(one));
```

...and the inverse would be:

```
var one = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('CreateEvent'));
```